Diagnosing SSH Issue Between Specific Pair of Machines
I am struggling to diagnose an ssh error that I'm only seeing when trying to connect from one specific machine (client A) to another specific machine (server).
Ping works, so I can see the server on the network and reach it from client A.
ping <server ip address>

When I try to ssh, I get the following two error messages. (First on the first attempt, second message on any following attempts.)
Connection closed by <server ip address> port 22

Received disconnect from <server ip address> port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from <server ip address> port 22

When I check the logs on the server, I see no indication that a connection was even initiated (by the client) and rejected (by the host).
However, I am able to ssh into another machine (client B) from client A, and then ssh into the server from client B. That login shows up in the server's logs.
I'm unsure how to diagnose this further. Something is clearly getting blocked or dropped, but it's not clear to me where in the network or how to determine that.
When I run the following from Client A:
ssh -vvv <user>@<server ip address>

I get the following output:
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3, OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <server ip address> is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to <server ip address> [<server ip address>] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <server ip address>:22 as '<user>'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from <server ip address>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:<server key>
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from <server ip address>
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '<server ip address>' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<user>@<server ip address>'s password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 1
Received disconnect from <server ip address> port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from <server ip address> port 22


It's good that you have a working client "B" to compare against.  Try diffing the he result from running this command on both "A" and "B":  ssh -G <user>@<server ip address>  ...that output includes options in effect AFTER reading the system's /etc/ssh/config and your users ~/.ssh/config.
Once you know what individual options are different between the 2 clients, you can dig into man ssh_config see how those options might be interfering on "A"
